# sparql xml how to extract this elements?

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, sparql, element

I want to extract an elements `geo:lat` but i don't know how

I did this but it didn't work :

```
PREFIX fun: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/fn/>
PREFIX iter: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/iter/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX xmlns: <http://www.georss.org/georss>


GENERATE {
   ?id a  geo:SpatialThing;
       rdfs:label  ?name;
       geo:lat  "{?lat}"^^xsd:decimal;
       geo:long "{?long}"^^xsd:decimal .
}

SOURCE <http://wcf.tourinsoft.com/Syndication/cdt37/A716E167-B408-45AA-BEAB-01E466942A8C/Objects> AS ?source
ITERATOR iter:XPath(?source,"/feed/entry") AS ?it
WHERE {
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/id/text()") AS ?id)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/title/text()") AS ?name)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/lat/text()") AS ?lat)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/geo:long/text()") AS ?long)    
}
```

I need to get the information in `feed/entry/geo:long` , my problem is the name of this element `geo:long`.

I have a list with point of interest and i am trying to get the name and the latitude and longitude of these POI with this
 https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/playground.html

Comment: Ehm, it would be good if say that you're doing as you're using SPARQL-Generate API  - clearly this is not standard SPARQL...

Comment: And *"didn't work"* is the worst description of a problem ...

Comment: Ok, I tried it in the online-demo - it doesn't bind lat and long

Comment: As @ASKW said, many functions (`GENERATE`, `ITERATE` ...) are not part of the SPARQL 1.1 Standard. It was disturbing at first sight

Comment: i am in traineeship and my supervisor tell me to use this https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/language.html

Comment: There is some namespace issue with the XML. Use this as workaround: `SOURCE <http://wcf.tourinsoft.com/Syndication/cdt37/A716E167-B408-45AA-BEAB-01E466942A8C/Objects> AS ?source
ITERATOR iter:XPath(?source,"/feed/entry") AS ?it
WHERE {
  BIND(URI(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/id/text()")) AS ?id)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/title/text()") AS ?name)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/*[name()='geo:lat']/text()") AS ?lat)
  BIND(fun:XPath(?it,"/entry/*[name()='geo:long']/text()") AS ?long)    
}`

Comment: *[name()='geo:lat'] that's what I was looking for, thank you